# cannot connect php to postgres database using pg_connect

Tags: php, database, postgresql, connection

I just try to connect my php code to postgres database but unfortunately it is not work, here is my code :

```
<?php
ini_set ("display_errors", "1");
error_reporting(E_ALL);
   $host        = "host=127.0.0.1";
   $port        = "port=5432";
   $dbname      = "dbname=public";
   $credentials = "user=postgres password=postgres";

   $db = pg_connect( "$host $port $dbname $credentials"  ) or die('Could not connect');;
   if(!$db){
      echo "Error : Unable to open database\n";
   } else {
      echo "Opened database successfully\n";
   }
```

browser result :

**Warning: pg_connect(): Unable to connect to PostgreSQL server: FATAL: database "public" does not exist in /var/www/test/pgtest.php on line 11**

anybody know what is wrong here ?

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure the name of database is 'public'? As fas as I remember 'public' is a name of default schema inside the PostgreSQL database.

Please make sure the database 'public' really exists.

Comment: I also tried to connect `testdb` that just I created and it is still gives same error:  Warning: pg_connect(): Unable to connect to PostgreSQL server: FATAL: database testdb does not exist in /var/www/test/pgtest.php on line 11

Answer (score 1):

From the command line, become the postgres user, start psql, and issue the \list command to list your databases.  Be sure the database you're trying to open is in the list.

Be sure your pg_hba.conf file allows the database to be opened.

Remove everything except $dbname from the pg_connect call and allow the API to use the defaults.  Add parameters back as indicated by the error message(s).

Answer (score 0):

sorry but finally I found that my question was wrong,  `public` and `testdb` are Schemes inside `postgres` database,